# TypeError: Object of type dict_values is not JSON serializable while using spreadsheet

Tags: python, dictionary, spreadsheet, gspread

I'm trying to update my google spreadsheet with the corresponding value of the keys from a dictionaries.

it's giving me an error, I'm not sure why
Here's my code below.

```
import datetime
from csv import reader
import csv
import json
import re
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import pandas as pd

def colnum_string(n):
    string = ""
    while n > 0:
        n, remainder = divmod(n - 1, 26)
        string = chr(65 + remainder) + string
    return string

total_value = {'Others': 350831.04, 'Q-labs': 3119.02, 'Practice': 2026.24, 'Account': 1068.04, 'SUPPORT': 988.45, 'Aflac': 807.65, 'Central': 392.77, 'SAVINGS': 339.2, 'PLAN': 329.79, 'MCD': 305.29, 'DU': 139.35, 'Val': 135.69, 'TAX': 133.55, 'School': 100.38, 'Service': 97.59, 'Charges': 78.59}

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
sheet = client.open('Data').worksheet('Daily-Data')
ans = sheet.col_values(1)
ans.pop(0)
length = len(total_value.values())
vals = total_value.values()

for key in total_value.keys():
    for j in ans:
        if key == j:
            sheet.add_cols(1) 
            col = sheet.col_count
            col_string = colnum_string(col+1)
            sheet.update(col_string+str(1),"testing")
            for i in range(2,length+2):
                sheet.update(col_string+str(i),total_value.values())
```

Here is the full Error that I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "spread.py", line 45, in <module>
    sheet.update(col_string+str(i),total_value.values())
  File "C:\Users\Data \Desktop\devops-scripts\env\lib\site-packages\gspread\utils.py", line 592, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Data \Desktop\devops-scripts\env\lib\site-packages\gspread\client.py", line 61, in request
    response = getattr(self.session, method)(
  File "C:\Users\Data \Desktop\devops-scripts\env\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 602, in put
    return self.request('PUT', url, data=data, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Data \Desktop\devops-scripts\env\lib\site-packages\google\auth\transport\requests.py", line 464, in request
    response = super(AuthorizedSession, self).request(
  File "C:\Users\Data \Desktop\devops-scripts\env\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 528, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "C:\Users\Data \Desktop\devops-scripts\env\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 456, in prepare_request
    p.prepare(
  File "C:\Users\Data \Desktop\devops-scripts\env\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 319, in prepare
    self.prepare_body(data, files, json)
  File "C:\Users\Data \Desktop\devops-scripts\env\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 469, in prepare_body
    body = complexjson.dumps(json)
  File "C:\Users\Data \AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
```

TypeError: Object of type dict_values is not JSON serializable

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that `dict_values` are not JSON serializable.

Seeing how you have a loop, perhaps you meant to iterate over the values:

```py
            for i,value in enumerate(total_value.values()):
                sheet.update(col_string+str(i+2),value)
```